# Can Puzzle ring drop torment only legendaries on torment?

Tags: diablo-iii

I read that the puzzle ring has a chance to drop legenderies and I was wondering if these would include torment only legenderies if playing on torment.

Comment: Just read the question you linked and it didn't contain the answer to my question

Comment: I voted to close as it is a duplicate of the other question, however I agree with you in the sense that the accepted answer does not answer your particualr question. I asked the original answerer to answer your interrogation, you can check back later if the answer has been updated :)

Comment: Well, let's hope a rare knowledgeable person would drop a note somewhere :-)

Comment: @WizLiz, but this question is not even in the other question. So, how is this a duplicate? It is a similar question but this particular question is not in the "Duplicate". This should be re-opened.

Comment: @prolink007 Even though the other question doesnt adress this particular issue the title "How does the post 2.0 puzzle ring work ?" was misleading in the sense that I expected a general question about this ring's mechanic. I felt it was redundant to have them both. However after rereading the FAQ, it appears I was mistaken and now the question is reopened. Let's hope someone can answer this :).

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly it will drop torment specific items. However, I cannot find any blue posts or hard evidence that it does.

Someone posted on the [Diablo 3 forums](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12675247726#1) saying they had a [Tal Rashas Allegiance](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/tal-rashas-allegiance) drop from the goblin.